# How to Deploy sample war file onto azure app service created using terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-machine, azure-storage-account

I am trying to deploy a .war file on Azure webapp. I have created a app service through terraform and a storage container. I uploaded my sample .war file to the container. I want to copy this .war file from container and deploy onto the app service I created. How can I do this just within azure and terraform?

Any leads appreciated.

Storage container containing .war file:
[image: Storage container containing .war file]

Azure appservice created using terraform:
[image: Azure appservice created using terraform]

Please help me with all the steps.

I tried copying the file from the container to the azure appservice by deploying to the deployment center but did not find a manual option to deploy the war file. All are linked to CI/CD deployments. How can I internally deploy the .war file within azure and terraform?

Comment: Please provide the terraform code you tried.

Answer (score 0):

To deploy a `.war` file from Azure Blob Storage to an Azure Web App using Terraform only is not recommended. Terraform is good for creating your infrastructure and configuring it. for Deployment, You should still try and use a Deployment Script. Below is what I will recommend.

1. **Blob Storage**: Ensure your `.war` file is in Azure Blob Storage.
2. **SAS Token**: Generate a Shared Access Signature (SAS) token for the blob for secure download.
3. **Kudu REST API**: Use a script that deploys the `.war` file via the Kudu REST API.
4. **Deployment Pipeline**: Use a deployment pipeline in azure devops or any other CI/CD Tool to run the script and deploy.

Bash Script (`deploy_war.sh`):

```bash
WEBAPP_NAME="your_webapp_name"
RESOURCE_GROUP="your_resource_group"
WAR_FILE_URL="https://your_storage.blob.core.windows.net/container/file.war?${SAS_TOKEN}"
PUBLISH_PROFILE=$(az webapp deployment list-publishing-profiles --name $WEBAPP_NAME --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP --query "[?publishMethod=='MSDeploy'].{user:userName,pass:userPWD}" -o tsv)
USERNAME=$(echo $PUBLISH_PROFILE | awk '{print $1}')
PASSWORD=$(echo $PUBLISH_PROFILE | awk '{print $2}')
curl -X POST -u $USERNAME:$PASSWORD -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"packageUri\":\"$WAR_FILE_URL\"}" "https://$WEBAPP_NAME.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/wardeploy"
```

**Edited to provide information about how to do this in terraform.**

Below are steps to achieve this using Terraform:

- Generate SAS Token

In your Terraform configuration, generate a SAS token for the blob:

```
resource "azurerm_storage_account_sas" "example" {
  connection_string = azurerm_storage_account.example.primary_connection_string
  https_only        = true

  start  = "2023-01-01"
  expiry = "2024-01-01"

  permissions {
    blob {
      read  = true
      write = false
      delete = false
      list  = false
      add   = false
      create = false
    }
  }

  services {
    blob  = true
    queue = false
    table = false
    file  = false
  }

  resource_types {
    service   = false
    container = false
    object    = true
  }
}
```

- Deploy using Kudu REST API

This step isn't straightforward to do directly from Terraform, but you can use a provisioner to run a local script that uploads the `.war` file to your Web App using the Kudu REST API.

Here's a basic example using `curl`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Variables
WEBAPP_NAME="your_webapp_name"
RESOURCE_GROUP="your_resource_group"
WAR_FILE_URL="https://your_storage_account.blob.core.windows.net/your_container/your_file.war?${SAS_TOKEN}"

# Get publishing profile for the Web App
PUBLISH_PROFILE=$(az webapp deployment list-publishing-profiles --name $WEBAPP_NAME --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP --query "[?publishMethod=='MSDeploy'].{user:userName,pass:userPWD}" -o tsv)

# Extract username and password
USERNAME=$(echo $PUBLISH_PROFILE | awk '{print $1}')
PASSWORD=$(echo $PUBLISH_PROFILE | awk '{print $2}')

# Use Kudu REST API to deploy the war file
curl -X POST -u $USERNAME:$PASSWORD \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -d "{\"packageUri\":\"$WAR_FILE_URL\"}" \
     "https://$WEBAPP_NAME.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/wardeploy"
```

To use this script with Terraform, you'd incorporate it as a provisioner in your Terraform code:

```
resource "azurerm_app_service" "example" {
  # ... your existing configuration ...

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "./deploy_war.sh"
    environment = {
      SAS_TOKEN = azurerm_storage_account_sas.example.sas
    }
  }
}
```

Using provisioners in Terraform is often considered a last resort. They can make your Terraform configurations less predictable and harder to maintain.

Comment: I am using terraform currently. So I would want to know how to deploy the sample .war file onto azure app service so that once I click on the app service URL it should open the webpage.

Comment: @Lekha I have updated the answer with steps for Terraform.

Comment: I tried adding the SAS token in terraform but it Didn't work out. Can you provide me with the code?